# selecting multiple table row using shift key and control key is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi i have a editable table which is created by using java script.here i use some code for selection process .i want select table row using control key and shift key . i get the code from 
  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/g8Rpe/ here. this example shown for html table .but my table is daynamic one 
the code is here:

```js
        /******for table**************/
        $(function () {
            function tableCreate() {
                var body = document.body,
                tbl = document.createElement('table');


                tbl.style.width = '100%';

                tbl.style.borderCollapse = 'collapse';

                for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                    var tr = tbl.insertRow();
                    tr.setAttribute("data-id", i, 0);
                    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

                        var td = tr.insertCell();
                        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(''));


                    }

                }

                $("body").append(tbl);
                $("td").addClass("mainheading4")

                $("tr").on("onmousedown=RowClick(this,false)")
            }
            tableCreate();
            //******************for editable table*************************//

            $('td').click(function () {
                $('td').attr('contenteditable', 'true');
            })


            //************for multiple selection*****************//
            var lastSelectedRow;
            var trs = document.getElementById('table').tBodies[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');

            // disable text selection
            document.onselectstart = function () {
                return false;
            }

            function RowClick(currenttr, lock) {
                if (window.event.ctrlKey) {
                    toggleRow(currenttr);
                }

                if (window.event.button === 0) {
                    if (!window.event.ctrlKey && !window.event.shiftKey) {
                        clearAll();
                        toggleRow(currenttr);
                    }

                    if (window.event.shiftKey) {
                        selectRowsBetweenIndexes([lastSelectedRow.rowIndex, currenttr.rowIndex])
                    }
                }
            }

            function toggleRow(row) {
                row.className = row.className == 'selected' ? '' : 'selected';
                lastSelectedRow = row;
            }

            function selectRowsBetweenIndexes(indexes) {
                indexes.sort(function (a, b) {
                    return a - b;
                });

                for (var i = indexes[0]; i <= indexes[1]; i++) {
                    trs[i - 1].className = 'selected';
                }
            }

            function clearAll() {
                for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
                    trs[i].className = '';
                }
            }

        });
```

```css
body{font-size:62.5%;}
td { padding: 0.2em 0.4em; }
.selected { background: lightBlue } 
    .mainheading4{
     border: 1px solid;
    border-color: lightgray;
    width:33.3%;
   height:17px;
   font-size:15px;
   padding-left: -5px;
 
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

i use

> $("tr").on("mousedown=RowClick(this,false)") <
>                            for  getting mouse event.

but its not taken.

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of wrong doings.

1) Assign id to table without which you will not get table rows as in below line

var trs = document.getElementById('table').tBodies[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');

E.g. In your tableCreate method add below lines of code.

```
        var body = document.body,
        tbl = document.createElement('table'),
        tableId = document.createAttribute('id');
        tableId.value = "table";
        tbl.setAttributeNode(tableId);
```

2) Second register mouse down event like suggested by feela,

```
    $(document).on('click', 'tr', function () {
        RowClick(this, false);
    });
```

Hope it will resolve your issue.

Comment: I didn't get your query...As per your initial question you want to select rows based on Control key or Shift key. Take a look on [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/3gb7253L/3/) .Please elaborate "I want select single row without using control key" ?

Comment: @ deepak ok its good working.but editable table is not working

Comment: @aswathy Please explain what exactly is not working, so that I can try to help you with that ?

Comment: selection is ok .you know my table is editable one but now the editing is not working  

 $('td').click(function () {
                $('td').attr('contenteditable', 'true');
            })

this part is i used for editable

Comment: @aswathy Since your table is loading dynamically, you should register click event on "td" using "on" method.  E.g. $(document).on('click', 'td', function(){     $(this).attr('contenteditable', 'true');    });

Comment: sorry i don't get it .can you please change it in your "working example"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117407/discussion-between-deepak-kumar-and-aswathy).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid syntax for `on`. See: http://api.jquery.com/on/

What you probably meant was:

```
$("tr").on("mousedown", function(event) {
    RowClick(event.target, false);
});
```

Comment: i try this code instead of $("tr").on("mousedown=RowClick(this,false)")  but no change in the result